# Anonymous array indexing instead of a switch statement?

Tags: java, switch-statement, indexoutofboundsexception, anonymous-arrays

In Java, I find the following code much cleaner and easier to maintain than the corresponding bulky `switch` statement:

```
try {
  selectedObj = new Object[] {
    objA,
    objB,
    objC,
    objD,
  }[unvalidatedIndex];
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
  selectedObj = objA;
}
```

opposed to

```
switch (unvalidatedIndex) {
  case 0:
    selectedObj = objA;
    break;

  case 1:
    selectedObj = objB;
    break;

  case 2:
    selectedObj = objC;
    break;

  case 3:
    selectedObj = objD;
    break;

  default:
    selectedObj = objA;
}
```

Is the former considered an acceptable practice? I am aware that it's not the most efficient one as it involves allocating an array and catching an exception. Would it cause something undesirable when `unvalidatedIndex` is out of range (although the exception is handled)?

If possible, would you suggest something cleaner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first approach is fine.

However, it is better to check the index first:

```
Object[] arr = new Object[] { ... };

if (i < 0 || i >= arr.length)
    i = 0;
selectedObj = arr[i];
```

Comment: Nice, but that pollutes the namespace with an additional identifier `arr` that's used just once. On the other hand, `arr.length` can be substituted with the constant `4` if an anonymous array is used, but that incurs a maintenance cost of always keeping this constant and the array in sync. I know I sound picky, but I'm asking this out of curiosity.

Comment: @Blagovest: Wrap it in `{ }` to make an inner scope and hide the variable.  Or make a `static` function that takes an index and an `Object...` and returns an object.

Answer (score 2):

It is not an acceptable practice. Exceptions are for errors handling, not for program flow.
Also exceptions are VERY SLOW.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
if(index < arr.length && index >= 0){
    obj = arr[index];
}else{
    obj = defaultValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both are antipatterns. Just test the index for range membership yourself. There might be a way to use an `enum` in many actual cases.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, though I have no doubt some will disagree, I would do:

```
switch (unvalidatedIndex) {
    case 0 : selectedObj = objA; break;
    case 1 : selectedObj = objB; break;
    case 2 : selectedObj = objC; break;
    case 3 : selectedObj = objD; break;
    default: selectedObj = objA; break;
    }
```

It's clean, compact, efficient, and really easy to understand.

I would hesitate to include the `case 0`, that being the `default` case.

Answer (score -1):

```
    int index = 4;

    ArrayList<String> myObjects = Lists.newArrayList("a", "b", "c", "d");
    Object o = index  < myObjects.size() && index >= 0 ? myObjects.get(index) : null;
    System.out.println(o);
```

Lists comes from Guava.

Comment: You _really_ don't need an `ArrayList` for that.